# Optimize WCF CAll

Tags: wcf

I have a database call which gives me 40 columns and 75000 rows, I am using a WCF service to get the data to client , my method returns this object to the client and  after getting the data and into an object to send to the front end it takes atleast 5 secs. How can I optomize this.

Comment: "How can I opt[i]mize this" - don't send all the data?

Comment: But I need full data  at once

Comment: How fast is the network link? How much data are you sending (MB)? How are you hosting the WCF service? Maybe 5 seconds is as fast as possible?

Comment: you might get some optimization if you use net tcp binding (or at least binary encoding) but in general as Mitch said - use a finder grained operation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are downloading the entire database to the client.

The best optimisation would then be to only download information to the client that you really need to download, and do not download it until it is required.

- A person is not going to browse 75000 records. Even if they did you could use paging.
- If the client is using this data to do calculations, then these calculations should be done on the server.